# Is there a way in scala to produce a generic instance without an example instance?

Tags: generics, scala, factory, traits

I was playing with creating a generic factory as follows:

```
trait Factory[T] { def createInstance():T = new T() }
val dateFactory = new Factory[Date](){}
val myDate = dateFactory.createInstance()
```

The 'new T()' doesn't compile, as T is undefined until runtime.  I know that I can get it to work by passing in an instance of the class to some method (ie.  createInstance(classOf[Date]) )

I am asking if there is some introspection magic that could replace 'new T()' so that I can create my super simple factory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will work:

```
class Factory[T : ClassManifest] {
  def
  createInstance(): T =
    (implicitly[ClassManifest[T]]).erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

*if* the class for which it is instantiated has a default (zero-arg) constructor.

Comment: I'm going to take this excellent answer as a clue that it cannot be done with a trait.

Comment: Sorry, I should have pointed that out. "traits cannot have type parameters with context bounds" (quoth the compiler)